# Change TextView text from another class using interface

Tags: java, android, interface

I'm trying to make some utils functions to use in a bigger app later(download file from url, upload file to url etc)
So in MainActivity I have only 2 buttons that on click call static methods from Utils class.
However, I want on MainActivity to have some indicators of how things working on download/upload methods(connecting, connection success/fail, percent of download etc) so I put on MainActivity a TextView that will show that. I made an interface ICallback that contains void setConnectionStatus(String status) and from Utils class I use this to send to MainActivity the status.

Here are some parts of the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ICallback {

Button btnDownloadDB, btnUploadDB, btnUploadPics;
TextView txtStatus;
ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initialize stuffs
    initViews();

    //Setting listeners
    btnDownloadDB.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        txtStatus.setText(R.string.connecting);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Utils.downloadFile(DOWNLOAD_DB, DB_FILE_NAME);
    });
}

@Override
public void setConnectionStatus(String status) {
    Log.d("MIHAI", status);
    txtStatus.setText(status);
}
```

The interface :

```
public interface ICallback {
void setConnectionStatus(String status); }
```

And the Utils class :

```
public class Utils {

static ICallback callback= new MainActivity();

public static void downloadFile(String downloadURL, String fileName) {

    IFileTransferClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(IFileTransferClient.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = client.downloadFile(downloadURL);

    responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d("MIHAI", "connection ok");
            callback.setConnectionStatus("Connection successful");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MIHAI", "err...fail");
            callback.setConnectionStatus("Connection failed. Check internet connection.");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem appear on MainActivity, when I try to set text of the txtStatus TextView getting a null reference error even if the txtStatus is initialized on initViews() method.
The Logs are working fine so I get the right status in MainActivity. I tried to initialize the TextView again in that function before seting the text and im getting : "*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:183)*"

Is there any chance to make this work?
Thank you for reading.

Kind regards,
Mihai

Comment: Is the error thrown from the listener or the setConnectionStatus method?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your solution but the main one is this line:

```
static ICallback callback= new MainActivity();
```

First of all, **never hold a static reference to Activity, Fragment, Context or any Context related classes**. These classes are either bound to a `Context` or represent the `Context` itself. You may leak memory this way. But that is the other problem.

What is the actual problem in your code is that `new MainActivity()` in `Utils` class creates an absolutely different instance of `MainActivity` that has nothing to do with `MainActivity` that is responsible for displaying your UI in the runtime.

What you should do instead is pass an instance of `ICallback` to the function as an argument:

```
public static void downloadFile(String downloadURL, String fileName, ICallback callback) {
...
}
```

And remove `static ICallback callback= new MainActivity();`.

*Note: when you pass a callback object to a function make sure when it is called your `Activity` is not in a finished state.*

Comment: Thank you very much. Did what you suggested and works. Please, tell me what are the other problems with the solution. I really want to learn more. Thank you!